# CoordinatorLayout Behavior not working when RecyclerView or NestedScrollView scroll programmatically

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, material-design, material-components-android, mdc-components

I have `AppBarLayout` and `BottomNavigationView` that both collapse during scroll.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".presentation.MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_menu"
            app:title="@string/home"
            app:subtitle="@string/assets"
            app:titleCentered="true"
            app:subtitleCentered="true"/>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    // NestedScrollView or RecyclerView
    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.behavior.HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Calling `smoothScrollToPosition(0)` and `smoothScrollTo(0, 0)` to programmatically scroll `RecyclerView` and `NestedScrollView` does not trigger the CoordinatorLayout Behavior for AppBarLayout and BottomNavigationView.

For RecyclerView,we can call `startNestedScroll` to trigger the coordinate behavior like this.

```
rv.startNestedScroll(ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL, ViewCompat.TYPE_NON_TOUCH)
rv.smoothScrollToPosition(0)
```

We trigger it every time back press is called.

```
if (recyclerView.canScrollUp()) {
    recyclerView.smoothScrollUpWithCoordinator()
} else {
    super.onBackPressed()
}
```

However there is a subtle bug here as sometimes it does not scroll all the way up, if you just slightly scroll the list and the `AppBarLayout` and `BottomNavigationView` collapse, calling the above code will scroll only up to most second item based on my checking.

For NestedScrollView `startNestedScroll` does not work at all.

I don't like the idea of manually expanding `AppBarLayout` and `BottomNavigationView`.
How to scroll programmatically where it will trigger views' CoordinatorLayout Behavior?

[Screen record 1](https://doc-30fg-2p50-issuetracker.googleusercontent.com/attachments/6ugsl664md3oma7d9qe0i8a8ar3l3hpd/2jt83kbl7drf4rlmv5c8qp2mqohrk6hm/1700839800000/460887/115846262492303161025/313013679::48657734::460887?dat=AFNnbnmDGxWIv5SapRL9afwZAR1fQM8lB3fY31Kl_sIu3via1tlVSKv_PQxysjBgG7YeOqpAazjDUggZkQ0AjZmpgkPywn7DZ4E3189w0WFEKye9-3lmar8cMo4rF6OWNUf9t9YNzgoDnmtg7cIm181yYADYirow2jCXcO2XdirbTvzhgu7Qs9WI4nUEyPnv5KiQTlWGth8RcWHaqoq-JGt1XcmExqHqaTdN0jfaVMCqf0-rmedMjdbj50Q3PZFpQQ_vkboMOKtPkVOT36Qo3h_-TjAOPe5mfnwje_RyMt9xGtj1wiFHkOoBKki1_pWF_jCauHHNnyhqtSCMgJaajORzpa1KJODcxUuya-yS6tcfNWos3Zk6AjoOZsIEiOq6kbg2cPQYnjEmXZf8f0K25twM9obGUJ25J_sk1RgfYnsTyDzZcTzzRXL9-NOE4SK4Om4SLgL3YoTbANTy7VdAmADFmf6pETpY9wBvtmugdRkRwbnPOPX_1TsikdSEt5FI2AxCMszIvDLl9unyweSusUKB6W5B6i2R_JwBsMvM2vxlb5A2m5hlC7cSMMC_Q-u-tRimmZSbdZJUqarnMWDVwA6Aj9LWeumtlMrzllhtRTRKqt88aHBIAVdp_v_cTybE3ehuNM5Gt8R_ckM3Tud7qM06WzVuvxMFk0YO8CFNc8Ra-H9xH3y8DsWjBOJ31Ag-7hZR3K9MX4Y1mpO3vVHaLEVSUd1iua3ne4N9-nHrXxunMmO5OWLjWjdczwiPKQkzgxTcfQdoXOFPz0HGi9JRkLDZhHpr3z0UJMgMb8laB-n49O5bTCpZEY8_y6LzLMwzpVLBiLqVFG-ci6SAkxShj8KNpCB0iY-cpuK_c9XoI-7kD8LPfTSb5I4hgR6NzftrVcsihQbbyKy0KQnq9jbySDCatLVMs5EpRPn0fA9GRhT9dQkH5Ly7hhiEeYXmBhod4M0thAlasef9BeDddZyXR-o2nG8rncFnt4zHYsv4pLtvL8SPV1qxaYh9u7XACGkjt4AwCNtRuQgu&u=0&s=1&q=AN9yeQJY0a32u4fdnh5aeZqkSxp9tOnti_AzbhzBErOGJR9fnC-jLkXR7i5ZWfpEj864AW3WXnpbjnZUxIAbI6j6A1Onsw&download=false&nonce=s9ml1ue1q1llg&user=115846262492303161025&hash=7ldv7mnqejqlshrom8g1eoisbghnkpcg)
[Screen record 2](https://doc-1i8g-2p50-issuetracker.googleusercontent.com/attachments/6ugsl664md3oma7d9qe0i8a8ar3l3hpd/du0hok8nm5alu3a98ht1flodg2aik1fc/1700839800000/460887/115846262492303161025/313013679::48657735::460887?dat=AFNnbnmz4AnqIhzYZdCfXm5usecyttq-DWoGcO5e4Q9RDvkqrgttgz6zHzQxjAbIAy4_XV3B-7A-O4FMCWSdm9c_5JOYLzQS1B26etOVa8FHcyt1fJ9ZQ1Rw2zeKGzPE-OX2B3wVsB7ekesUPLqvl5n1UD_kKWeEYURqSUGJkoSFoukUxzcsZIfKYKr3tCKk19iFWMg_HeMXMbMX4QYBKayxKHywIZxKY9lWAGTXA0uiTHPCm8ResvgCnYn4KPwQ7HzAXUCAbrH49uYvmc-nk1j5zmnpY_v1pe5UyZqT0kD_R2rLfwtRRL398JHRLHwfHagK2PR-pji0zUUMxOdSYglaHNfU7EtaA5bFvGz1LhPgFVjOSejowj2uSIkzuFaDlU8-WHMr0NoT5F-60wnrp8vqy3f7Op7aj5fmR3v2we-xOk_MOnvLJknJb3KDn7PKCioQr1BiydTB5u4khh3-MFZXq5f2k9WgsxJ-IDc5pmCy46RW_SS2QZWW8JjjHmEjMCM-kppWxCeBB7ftk-q20fjMqC8KlN4_ubKjrwR1jGxAMvvv6j9II9JaMdNwn5FIKJvLvSPGl2UA1yQBi6yrmHfGhDaLJGcrVd1nFiBtXrqeMJGKOsk7ZAMOgvC0tahHfCT239nVYVMKJminrXZsfmvFtjnPR5yF48tUVEVUVNA7bxgxs0rxyGRGxPPoq7pF1y-ooDoP-98-rJq7P1OuMTEI9Pq6d2AoVT9eAsUWQSwmyH2cVuWlS6xeD88_ARByitrql7jE_pTQ-e1AuIDOIiAMwn2n5VAXYNS7PMBJrQDudmar-T-1awjtCPQ52Fo3mW_BDLuA0AO_NCYprUCLgfGhqzev4QrMvTSg7vz0QzrjDyrHsbLUYo15Z2zZcXp5Hwt3PDBg2T3bgImKp2WmWM2BVipXo_afZfcSlZPG1MaSzaAmBfGfI_2Zw1iYO5vy0g78iKXyrc_ISsGdpv1XgEYmdecMqNdifVncksyydS8HuqvdKe6Nw9ORTcF9utFmSVkkAL3_bWwn&u=0&s=1&q=AN9yeQJzPJQuEmgLAibRsoDtwrYKM84tMAkltV_01wXlGowtiKgL-ZQfo0_nYItNsQGp9XCTT9A2Rg6LNTZiareuYqRM&download=false&nonce=hbimk8bb97stq&user=115846262492303161025&hash=u1n7o74isjbai8ckjsq9a3s9mvfeub9m)